# OnionPi with meek-amazon transport plugin

Tags: raspberry-pi

I'm living in China and GFW block Tor traffic anyway I installed the Tor bundle on my Ubuntu computer and was able to connect to the network with the "meek-amazon transport plugin" bridge.

I've successfully installed all the requirements to run my RPI2 (headless) 
as a Tor router.

My questions is:

How can I configure the torrc file (or any file in this case) to allow my RPI2/Tor router to connect to the "meek-amazon tp"?
Mind you, I am running headless so this all needs to be through ssh. Also, I'm in China so unless I can download something through http I can't git clone from anything dealing with tor.

Thanks!

Comment: The same question is cross-posted here: http://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/6538/how-to-install-a-transport-plugin-on-onionpi/6549#6549

Comment: please do not post same question multiple times